# Prove some properties of the $p$-adic norm

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I need to prove that the $p$-adic norm is an absolute value in the rational numbers, by an absolute value in a field $K$ I mean a function $|\cdot|:K \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that:

> $$\begin{align}
> \text{I)}&~~~~ |x|=0 \implies x=0\\
> \text{II)}&~~~~|x\cdot y|=|x|\cdot|y|\\
> \text{III)}&~~~~\text{The triangle inequality.}
> \end{align}
> $$

I do not know how to prove II) and III) for the $p$-adic norm.

I have for II) that:

$|x|_{p}·|y|_{p}=p^{-r}·p^{-a}=p^{-r-a}$ and $|x·y|_{p}=p^{-m}$.

How can $p^{-m}=p^{-r}·q^{-a}$?

Comment: For II), you want $\lvert xy\rvert_p = \lvert x\rvert_p\cdot \lvert y\rvert_p$, everything is with respect to the same prime $p$.

Comment: The prime $p$ is fixed, so you need to prove $|xy|_p=|x|_p|y|_p$ and $|x+y|_p\le |x|_p+|y|_p$

Comment: Yes I am sorry I fix it :)

Comment: What you really have is $|x·y|_{p}=|p^{-r} n \cdot p^{-a} m|_p=|p^{-r-a}   mn|_p =p^{-r-a}$. (Here $m$ and $n$ are just the ratios where you cant take $p$ as a factor anymore.)

Comment: I just proved that the RHS is equal to the LHS which you wrote in your question.

Comment: Good then we have :) II) Isnt it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (II), write

$q_1=p^mr, q_2=p^ns$ where $r,s\in\Bbb Q$ has numerator and denominator prime to $p$ and $m,n\in\Bbb Z$

Then

> $$|q_1q_2|_p=p^{-(n+m)}=p^{-n}p^{-m}=|q_1|_p\cdot|q_2|_p$$

For (III) assume, that $n> m$, then

$$|q_1+q_2|_p=p^{-m}|p^{n-m}s+r|_p=p^{-m}\le p^{-m}+p^{-n}$$

because

> $$p|(p^{n-m}s+r)\implies p\bigg|\big\lbrace (p^{n-m}s+r)-p^{n-m}s\big\rbrace =r$$

a contradiction, proving the triangle inequality there.

If $n=m$ write

$$|q_1+q_2|_p=p^{-n}|r+s|_p$$

Then since the common denominator of $r,s$ is still prime to $p$, we can reduce to the case $r,s\in\Bbb Z$.

But then it's easy, we just need to show, for integers, $r,s$ that

$$|r+s|_p\le |r|_p+|s|_p.$$

For this we note that if $r=p^nr', \; s=p^ns'$ with $\gcd(p,r')=\gcd(p,s')=1$ then $r+s=p^n(r'+s')$ and if $p|(r'+s')$ then

> $$|r+s|_p\le p^{-n-1}\le 2p^{-n}=|r|_p+|s|_p$$

if $p\not |(r'+s')$ then

> $$|r+s|_p=|p^n|_p\cdot |r'+s'|= p^{-n}\le 2p^{-n}=|r|_p+|s|_p.$$

---

**Note:** By breaking things into cases like this we have an excellent observation: Almost always we have that $|q_1+q_2|_p=\max\{|q_1|_p, |q_2|_p\}$. And in the case that equality *doesn't* hold we have that $|q_1|_p=|q_2|_p$ which means all triangles in the $p$-adic world are isosceles, when we measure their lengths with this absolute value!

Comment: Thank for your helpful answer.  Can I ask how you are able to claim, while trying to prove the triangle inequality, that $p^{-m}|p^{n-m}s+r|_p=p^{-m}$. Also wheres the contradiction you claim later on?

Comment: @P-S.D the contradiction is that p divides r if it divides the sum of a multiple of p and r (basic number theory). That is also how we make the conclusion you ask about using the definition of the p-adic absolute value.

Comment: Thank you. Also how do you claim that $p|(p^{n-m}s+r)\implies p\bigg|\big\lbrace (p^{n-m}s+r)-p^{n-m}s\big\rbrace$

Comment: @P-S.D this is again, elementary number theory: if something divides two things then it divides their sum